# Windows Service vs Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: windows-services, workflow-foundation

I just had a quick overview about windows workflow foundation and it has mentioned that it is good for long running task. In my application when the user request for a task to do, it will take several hours to complete the task ( task is to get record from another server, do some operation and download it into a csv file ) . But the web application should allow the user to log out and the task will do in background. Currently I have implemented this using windows service. So my question is windows Workflow foundation is a good approach here to implement this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but not the best scenario. I advice you to use NServiceBus, in this case the web application will send a command and a NServiceBus windows service will receive that command and run your long running task.